# GeoServer WMS API hit counts model

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am working on a GeoServer API, which on request provides a WMS image in response.

My requirement is for the monitoring of the API hits, the number of objects displayed on the WMS response will be considered as the number of transaction or API hits.

But in the development of the above scenario, I am facing an issue as to how will I monitor the transaction hits of my clients who will be accessing my API?

Comment: There are no features in a WMS GetMap response.

Comment: okay not the features but the objects that are displayed on the map i need to count them to monitor the transaction?

Comment: You could try doing a corresponding WFS request in the background

Comment: That's the problem, i cannot use the wfs request due to security reasons ?

Comment: If WFS request is done in the background it should not be unsecure. But WMS does not necessarily show all the data because of scale dependent rendering and classification. Perhaps you should make another WMS request in the background with a vector based outputformat like KML and count the number of rendered vectors on the server side.

Comment: @user30184 can you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: I mean to make a request like https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&WIDTH=1601&HEIGHT=953&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&BBOX=35.161,-105.002,37.939,-100.335&CRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=
 and count how many Placemarks you have in the response.